# How to create a table with no columns in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite, create-table, tablecolumn, dbtable

I want to create table with no columns in sqlite3. It is possible in postgres database, but not in a sqlite3 one. Is there any way to achieve this, or is it simply not supported (maybe not in sql standard?) I have checked sqlite3 `CREATE TABLE` grammar and it seems, that there must be at least one column, but maybe I have missed something?

Comment: I am curious about what problem a zero-column table solves. Care to elaborate?

Comment: I am doing a pet project and working on tests. I could create empty table in postgres for test purpose, but the same automated test failed for sqlite. So I wanted to be sure if I am not doing anything wrong. Since empty tables are not supported by sql standards I don't need to care about it.

Comment: @Tim one might want to create empty tables and then go on adding columns.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Zero-column tables aren't supported in SQLite.  Or in the SQL standard either.

Comment: Interestingly, [it's possible in PostgreSQL](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/03/17/creating-tables-dum-and-dee-in-postgresql/), though

Comment: @LukasEder That... doesn't seem very useful beyond entirely academic purposes. PostgreSQL doesn't even require the FROM clause, so it doesn't need a DUAL table like Oracle does.

Comment: @BaconBits: You can implement some cool predicate logic in joins using these tables. No one said this was't academic :)

Comment: Zero-column tables are also possible in Access as in `CREATE TABLE NoColumns;`. Interesting that SQLite3 doesn't support this.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same question because I wanted a table with only the rowid field. While you may not be able to create a table without columns, you can make a table with only a rowid field as the primary key using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create table with only id column instead of creating empty table:

```
def create_table(DATABESE_NAME):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABESE_NAME)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rate_table(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT) ''')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot create a table with no columns in SQLite but you can easily create a table with one column which is empty string with `BLOB` type as shown below. *If specifying no type, the type is `BLOB` type according to [the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples):

```sql
CREATE TABLE person ("");
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person ([]);
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (``);
```

And, you can add a row if you want as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO person ("") values ('John');
```

Or:

```sql
INSERT INTO person ([]) values ('John');
```

Or:

```sql
INSERT INTO person (``) values ('John');
```

Or:

```sql
INSERT INTO person values ('John');
```

Comment: The question is: "How to create a table with **no** columns in SQLite?" Your code creates a table with 1 column with a name that is an empty string: https://dbfiddle.uk/nrvQii19

Comment: I don't know if I can call empty string a column. Is it possible to have a column without type in SQLite?

Comment: Yes it is possible: https://dbfiddle.uk/S_g9MFJM

Comment: Can I see the explanation about the column without type in SQLite doc?

Comment: Here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples, search for "no datatype specified".